# How can I teach Visual Studio Code about __fp16?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, arm, intellisense

I have a makefile project for a Cortex-M4F microcontroller compiled with the arm-none-eabi compiler, and I am using the __fp16 storage type for some floats. I am using Visual Studio Code to edit the code, and a makefile to compile.

My code compiles fine, but Visual Studio Code does not recognize the __fp16 storage type.

[image]

I am using c_cpp_properties.json to configure the compiler and a compile_commands.json.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/../**",
                "/usr/local/FreeRTOSv10.2.0/FreeRTOS/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "DEBUG=1",
                "FIRMWARE_VERSION=\"DUMMY\""
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gcc-arm-none-eabi-8-2018-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-mcpu=cortex-m4",
                "-march=armv7+fp",
                "-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16",
                "-mfloat-abi=hard",
                "-mfp16-format=ieee"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-arm",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "compileCommands": "${workspaceFolder}/compile_commands.json"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

How can I teach Visual Studio Code about the `__fp16` storage type? I thought it would discover the type with the `compilerArgs` settings, with the `-mfp16-format=ieee` argument, but it does not appear to make a difference (I've tried various combinations here...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an Intellisense error. Intellisense quickly compiles the code as you type, just to catch simple errors. But this isn't the full GCC compiler. Intellisense doesn't generate ARM code, it just checks for legal C++.

You can fool Intellisense by adding `__fp16=float` to `defines` in `c_cpp_properties.json`.  If the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) is right, that is **not** passed to the actual compiler, just to Intellisense.

Comment: I tried this and it does not work. According to the docs, it is because I am using a compile_commands.json file and the defines are only used when there is no compile_commands file.

Comment: "It does not work"? That means your problem remains unchanged, i.e. the red Intellisense squiggle saying `__fp16` is undefined?

Comment: yes, that is right. According to the page you linked in the docs, the `defines` are only used if there is no compile_commands.json. I guess I could try to go w/o compile_commands.json....

Comment: @SolArnu: Another approach would along the lines of `#ifdef __INTELLISENSE__ #define __fp16 float #endif` in your code. But I don't know for certain if that macro works in VS Code.

Comment: That workaround works and it appears to be a documented feature at least for visual studio. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019